# Session 'app': Install failed. Installation failed Rerun ...Suddenly?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working properly but suddenly today I face this problem. When I want to run than its show this error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgQ1O.png

Comment: Try uninstalling the app using the command `adb uninstall YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME` and then try running again.

Comment: Check the mobile phone's permissions this usually happens when you have denied install or it is denied after certain time or permanently denied to install the app

Comment: Follow the @Susheel solutions. uninstall you packages, clean, rebuild and install. hope will it work.

Comment: I have no experience to uninstalling app using command. How can i do this??